# Would it be really an advantage to achieve multi-threading using web workers in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, performance, web-worker, single-threaded

I think the question is pretty explicit. JavaScript is single threaded and NodeJS still achieves incredible performances. We could think obvious that [multi-threading](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) would take NodeJS performances further, but it might be wrong in some cases.

For example, I'm currently building a [starter project](https://github.com/glemiere/nextjs-starter) using NextJS. I wonder if handling each request in a separate thread would be worth it.

Thank you!

Comment: From the README: “webworker-threads provides an asynchronous API for CPU-bound tasks that's missing in Node.js”. Sometimes you have a CPU-bound task and you want to write it in JavaScript. Without threads, you might implement that as a message queue with a pool of worker processes.

Comment: You need to describe the scenario you are trying to optimize.  Stack Overflow is not the right place for open-ended discussions.  List questions are automatically a problem.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Done ;) Thank to both of you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know in production mode nodeJs "usually" used as:

- nginx server (used as security layer and as HTTPS proxy)
- number of child NodeJs processes (amount === number of cores)

That means that all cores are used,

request is processed by single core,

server processes several requests at once

=== UPDATE ===

If you want to divide single request processing into several threads - then just remember that cross-process communication is expensive in NodeJS, and you need to delegate huge tasks to other threads/webworkers

If you see the need to split app into several threads - consider using microservices architecture, e.g. using http://senecajs.org/